# Class 'App/Board' not found . Why happen this error

Tags: laravel

I using relation of model on laravel.

when I access to viewpage but show error [Class 'App/Board' not found].

I have Board.php in App folder absolutely.

I have no idea what's wrong.

I spent 1hours .
please give me advice.

controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Board;
use App\Person;
use App\Http\Requests\PostRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class ReviewController extends Controller
{
    .
    .
    .
    public function show()
    {   
        $items_p = Person::all();
        $data = [
            'items_p' => $items_p
        ];
        return view('Review.show', $data);
    }
}
```

Board.php(In App folder)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Board extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'person_id',
        'message'
    ];


    public function getData()
    {
        return  $this->message;
    }
}
```

Person.php(In App folder)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Person extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
            'name'
    ];

    public function board()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App/Board');
    }
}
```

View(Review.show)

```
.
.
.
 <ul>
   <li>
     @foreach ($items_p as $item)
       {{$item->name}}
       {{$item->board->getData()}}
     @endforeach
   </li>
 </ul>
・
・
・
```

Comment: I suggest to use `return $this->hasOne(Board::class);` notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in slash. you have passed `/`. it should be `\`.

```
class Person extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
            'name'
    ];

    public function board()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Board');
    }
}
```